# correct way to handle logout from table row

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a app that uses a menu slider, and at the bottom of the menu there is a row for user the log out [this is how the menu looks like](http://puu.sh/4wVcC). I am having hard time trying to figure out a way to log the user to my splash screen[this is how my storyboard looks like](http://puu.sh/4wVke).

**What I would like to achieve**

When the user clicks log out row in the menu, I would like to perform a log out with [PFUser logOut];(I am using parse as a backend) and go back to my splash screen either instantiating the splash view using storyboard id or performing a manual modal segue or somehow magically calling the view from app delegate.

**What I have tried**

I tried  a [PFUser logout] and perform a manual segue to cellForRowAtIndexPath method like this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *CellIdentifier = [self.menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (indexPath.row == 5) {
        [PFUser logOut];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"logOutSegue" sender:self];
    }

     return cell;
}
```

I was able to log the user out and show my splash screen but this logs the user out as soon as I click the menu button(since indexPath.row == 5 all the time).

**two question**

If what I have tried is the right way, how can I recognize if the user click the logout row in the menu? 
If this is not the right way, what would be the efficient way to solve this problem?

If anyone can help me with this problem, I would really appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that you are calling that code from within the cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method of UITableView. This runs whenever the tableView loads the cell. Instead, you want to run when the user clicks the cell, so you need to use didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method of UITableView.

Take a look at the code below:

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row==5){
       [PFUser logOut];
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"logOutSegue" sender:self];
    }
}
```

Comment: Waow I just did exactly the same thing![this is how i figured it out](http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-handle-row-selection-in-uitableview/). Just an addition, I also had to add a segue from logout row to my splash menu. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it from

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

The best way to log out user is to prompt UIAlertView (Are you sure you want to log out? YES||NO) to make sure that he didnt missclick this button.
In delegate method of this alert view you should just pop your view from navigation stack (the best way is to popToRootViewController). You can do this also in storyboard.

Comment: the problem with this approach is, as soon as I open the menu, it will show the alert without me clicking the logout row(which is my problem in the first place).Problem is to identify that the user clicked the log out row. How can I recognize the click for the specific row